# Select SQLite Rows with First Timestamp after 1am of each day using Nodejs

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite, node-sqlite3

Using nodejs with the `node-sqlite3` library and given a sqlite table with a column `timestamp` that contains a timestamp string, such as:

```
+-----------------------------------+--------+      +
| timestamp                         | score  | .... |
+-----------------------------------+--------+      +
| 2022-02-22T00:49:56.184769483Z    | 1.056  |      |
| 2022-02-22T01:04:52.185208658Z    | 1.234  |      |
| 2022-02-22T01:19:51.779811366Z    | 1.432  |      |
           ...
| 2022-02-23T00:50:01.439211796Z    | 2.693  |      |
| 2022-02-23T01:05:57.290233187Z    | 2.792  |      |
          ...
```

how do you select the first row of each day after the time `01:00:00`?

In this example, the desired rows will be the ones with `timestamp` equal to:

- `2022-02-22T01:04:52.185208658Z`
- `2022-02-23T01:05:57.290233187Z`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER` as follows:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTR(timestamp, 1, 10)
                                 ORDER BY timestamp) rn
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE SUBSTR(timestamp, 12, 2) >= '01'
)

SELECT timestamp, score
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```